# Find sub-string / replace full-string with new value across entire data.frame in R

Tags: regex, r, dataframe, grepl

I have a large data frame with many columns. For a subset of these columns I would like to match on a substring and replace

An example of a subset of two columns looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(list(A=c("0/0:52,0:52:High_Confidence:99:0","0/0:2,0:2:Low_Confidence:3:0,3,45,1858","0/0:52,0:52:High_Confidence:99:0,135,1858","0/0:9,0:9:Low_coverage_High_quality:21:0,21,291"), B=c("0/0:5,0:5:Low_Confidence:15:0,15,194","0/0:21,0:21:High_Confidence:51:0,51,675","0/0:1,0:1:Low_Confidence:3:0,3,39","0/0:17,0:17:High_Confidence:48:0,48,609")))
```

I would like to use a grepl type command to replace fields with "Low_Confidence" in them with ./. across the entire data frame.

I've tried:

```
df[grepl(".*Low_Confidence.*", df)] <- "./." # replaces ALL values with ./.
df[agrep(".*Low_Confidence.*", df)] <- "./." # Does nothing

df[grep(".*Low_Confidence.*", df)] <- "./." 
df[grep("Low_Confidence", df)] <- "./."
```

Most of these return data.frames with all values in the relevant columns with ./. regardless of whether they match the Low_Confidence criteria or not.

I also tried converting the data.frame to a matrix

```
df  <- as.matrix(df)
df[df==".*Low_Confidence.*"]  <- "./." # does nothing
```

Without success. I know it's possible if I do this one column at a time, for example:

```
df$V85[grepl(".*Low_Confidence.*", df$V85)] <- "./."
```

But for 100s of columns that's highly repetitive.

So i'm looking for a solution that will find/replace with a wild card match the entire string (not just the matching text) in a data.frame across all, or a subset of columns (either will work).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert the columns to characters (this step is needed because your provided dataframe includes factors. Replacing values of factors this way lead to NAs), then replace the Low_Confidence cells with "./." using apply:

```
df1 <- apply(df,2,as.character)
df1[apply(df1,2,function(x) grepl("Low_Confidence",x))] <- "./."
```